# How to match through new line in regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

This is my code. I want to ignore whatever that is within ~~. Even if it contains new lines, white spaces. So that I can ignore the comments.

```
for letter in code :

    tok += letter                                   #adding each character to the token.

    if not is_str and (tok == " " or tok == "\n"):  
    #ignoring whitespaces and new line if it's not a string.
        tok = ""                                    #reseting each the iterator token.

    #Always always always remember. It's not lexer's job to generate errors
    #It's the work of parser. One thing should only do one thing.

    elif re.search(r'Enter', tok):
        tokens.append("ENTER")
        tok = ""

    elif re.search(r'~(.*?|\n*?)~',tok):            
    #to ignore the comments written within ~this~
        tok = ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no other `~` is allowed within `~` strings, you can use:

```
r'~[^~]*~'
```

This will match any character but `~`.

Comment: Thank you :) This can also work. Really Smart there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag:

> Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a
>   **newline**; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything except a newline.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'~(.*?)~', re.DOTALL)
```

**Trial**:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''~dksdjs
... sdjs~'''
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'~(.*?)~', re.DOTALL)
>>> pattern.search(s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='~dksdjs\nsdjs~'>
#                                                    ^
```